# should i not use backbone.js because it uses hashbangs?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, javascript-framework, hashbang

I'm new to backbone.js and like the idea of structuring javascript. However, i've read it relies on hashbangs which Twitter is trying to eradicate.

So my question is should I not use backbone.js due to this?

Comment: thanks Jed, what do you like about it best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone actually just uses a hash and not a hashbang. However if you enable [pushState](http://backbonejs.org/#History) than on modern browsers (pretty much anything other than IE) there will be no hash at all.

Comment: thanks Abraham, is enabling pushState a built-in option on backbone.js? can you explain a little further? i'm just a little confused because the browser is what "enables" pushState not you or I, just fyi, i am using jquery.pjax(),https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax, for pushState in capable browsers

Comment: By "enable pushState" I mean enable backbone's use of pushState when the browser supports it.